# "make" in a Fortran library results in "Command not found" error

Tags: g77

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and gcc version 4.4.3

I have been trying to install this library called SUPER_LU and there are some codes in it are written in Fortran. Typing "make" at the top level directory gives me the following errors

```
gaurish108@gaurish108-laptop:~/Desktop/Research Meetings/PETSC and SUper LU/SuperLU_4.0$ make
( cd INSTALL; make )
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gaurish108/Desktop/Research Meetings/PETSC and SUper LU/SuperLU_4.0/INSTALL'
g77  -o testdlamch dlamch.o lsame.o dlamchtst.o
***make[1]: g77: Command not found***
make[1]: *** [testdlamch] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gaurish108/Desktop/Research Meetings/PETSC and SUper LU/SuperLU_4.0/INSTALL'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

This has happened with me in the past also when i tried to download some math libraries?  always thought g77 cam bundles up with gcc. When I tried to install g77 separately with `sudo apt-get install g77`, this is what I got

```
gaurish108@gaurish108-laptop:~/Desktop/Research Meetings/PETSC and SUper LU/SuperLU_4.0$ sudo apt-get install g77[sudo] password for gaurish108: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package g77 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package g77 has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As of gcc 4.0, g77 has been replaced with gfortran.